# Display: none still shows a blank page (CSS issue)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a test page here: http://desertcinema.com/home-test/

I added an inline `display: none;` on one of the `<li>` here and I expected to  get a result like this by default: See image:

[image]

However, I don't know what happened but it actually leaves a blank space, like the image below:

[image]

I am wondering if how I can hide that list item without having that blank space there. Here's what my code looks like:

```
<ul class="portfolio-wrap">
    <li class="portfolio-box photography "> 
        <a class="gallery" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4bav1hxsgwj54nvaww.jpg" title="Concealment">
            <img src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" /> 
            <div class="mask"></div>
            <div class="line-folio"></div>
            <div class="line-folio1"></div>
            <h4>Concealment</h4>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="portfolio-box photography" style="display: none;"> 
        <a class="gallery" rel="gallery2" href="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/Mike-Full-Draw-30sp495yqivl82ubkxq5mo.jpg" title="Concealment">
            <img src="http://desertcinema.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/SKRE-9-30sp4baun93pvbri4pf1ts.jpg" alt="" /> 
                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="line-folio"></div>
                <div class="line-folio1"></div>
                <h4>Concealment</h4>
           </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea what I'm missing out? How can I hide an item without getting a blank space?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: Looks like there's something else that you've not included that causes the 5th (in the example) image to start a new row.

Comment: Curios, because if you remove the item vía debugger, the gap survives..

Comment: Can you just comment out the li instead of `display:none`?

Comment: @freedomn-m: There's lots of <li> there, I've only included the list item that has the issue. you can inspect element to see the codes on the next items.

Comment: If you don't want it displayed, why include it at all? Swap it for a different IMG, or do a display: none on hover

Comment: @NooBskie: nope. I just need to hide it. I am using fancybox to hide that element but that image it will show up on the gallery.under one category

Comment: the positions are precalculated, with some plugins, the translate3d shows this. I think the easiest solution is to remove the item from your list.

Comment: @RachelGallen: The reason why I am not taking it out is that it will show up the image on the popout (via fancybox plugin) so I just need to hide it but havign that issue of blank space.

Comment: @PaulJohnDiwa: As much as I would like too I can't.The reason why I am not taking it out is that it will show up the image on the popout (via fancybox plugin) so I just need to hide it but havign that issue of blank space.

Comment: @KimberleyWright the white space is not an 'issue', it's what's supposed to happen when you display:none, I.e. expected behaviour, I don't know why you expected otherwise.

Comment: okay here you go,     .portfolio-wrap.isotope > li:last-child{ transform: translate3d(1000px,0px,0px) !important

Comment: removing that list item from DOM do the trick, the library you are using is accountable for that hidden list too. remove that list from DOM and again fire the event. 

would be better if you read the provided properties of that library

Comment: *you can inspect element to see the codes on the next items"* - no, I can't access your (temporary?) test site, that's why *all relevant* code should be included in the question.  Maybe recreate in a fiddle.  Read this [mvce].

Comment: you can paste my answer on the console, maybe you can get the idea on how you could resolve this

Comment: @PaulJohnDiwa: Can't seem grasp the idea yet. Can we move this on chat?

Comment: @KimberlyWright. check my answer i think that's what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$allIsotopes = $('.portfolio-wrap.isotope').children('li');
$allIsotopes.last().css('transform',$allIsotopes.eq(3).css('transform'));
```

first we get all the .isotopes, (you can change the selector if you don't like the way it is) then get the last one and put it's css to the 4th .isotopes so we don't have to adjust everyone else

the solutions is temporary, i think the plugin your using is listening on the window resize or something

Comment: Can we move this on chat?

Answer (score 0):

one thing is for sure the columns are pre-calculated right after the page is loaded. What I will do in your case is create a class for the `li` element you want to hide example `portfolio-box-hidden` and in your css you could do

```
.portfolio-box-hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

The new class should override the class of the element you want to hide which is the 
`portfolio-box` class.

I browsed your `template.js` script and found the culprit that is related to pre-calculating the columns and is responsible for placing the element on their prospective position.

> By reading the isotope documentation, it automatically hides elements
>   not included on the filter. Try adding a filter on your `setProject`
>   Method located on your `template.js` file. below is the updated code

```
function setProjects() { 
    setColumns();
    container.isotope({filter: ':not(.hidden)'},'reLayout');
}
```

then add a class `hidden` on the li element you want to hide.

and add the code below to refresh the elements make sure to place it inside `document ready event`, you can remove the `seTimeout` method if the script is working fine, the `setTimeout` was only added to make sure that the method inside it will be executed after certain time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      $('.portfolio-wrap').isotope({filter: ':not(.hidden)'},'reLayout'); 
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: can we move on chat?

Comment: based on the isotope documentation you can also hide the elements not included on the filter,  I'll update my answer right away :)

Comment: Ok looking forward to it.

Comment: I added the codes under the counter...//Counter 
 
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 100,
            time: 2000
        });
    });  
 
  })(jQuery); 
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
  jQuery(".wpcf7-form").attr('id','ajax-form');  
});

 
 function setProjects() { 
    setColumns();
    container.isotope({filter: ':not(.hidden)'},'reLayout');
}

Comment: Do i need to define the class .hide{ display: none; } ??

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: It's actually just hiding things but it doesn't settle the blank space. I know your answer is too close.

Comment: Are you there mate?

Comment: remove the code you added after the counter and add this one $('.portfolio-wrap').isotope({filter: ':not(.hidden)'},'reLayout');

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you need to add the code inside document ready see the updated js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c915j5ou/2/ also make sure that template.js is loaded first :). I've just tested it on your site and the code is working fine. Try to load your site and paste the code $('.portfolio-wrap').isotope({filter: ':not(.hidden)'},'reLayout') and you'll see that it's working and hiding the element properly :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115719/discussion-between-allan-empalmado-and-kimberly-wright).

Comment: checking this mate

Comment: I also updated the last code and added the setTimeout to make sure that the script will be executed 500ms after page load.

Comment: If you want we can talk on the chat instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `position` of each `li` is been `calculated` at load time.
you just need to use the below piece of code will work for you.

I already use this `code` in your `website console` and its working.

Hope this helps :)
**Thanks**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".portfolio-wrap.isotope li").each(function(index){
  var style = $(this).attr("style");
  $(this).removeAttr("style");
  $(this).next("li").removeAttr("style");
  $(this).next("li").attr("style",style); 
});
});
```

[image]

Comment: its working, you have to use this `code` at the end of page.
also you have an error in your console may be thats the reason this `code` is not wokring.

Comment: can we move this to chat so that you can further check?

Comment: How can we move to chat here? or do we need to move to external? have some information like skype or so?

Comment: ? how can we move this to chat?

Comment: sorry! i don't have skype, plus i updated the `code` in answer lets try that i am 100% sure it will work, if not then https://web.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100005020968971 we can chat here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115716/discussion-between-kimberly-wright-and-m-tanzil).